# Load iframes 1 by 1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I found this script on an earlier post. I was trying to get this to work but I am not sure why it is not working.

```
$(function() {
  var iframes = $('iframe');
  var i = 0;
  (function next() {
      var iframe = iframes.eq(i++);
      if (iframe.length) {
          iframe.attr('src', iframe.data('src')).load(next);
      }
  })();
});
```

I get the error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: url.indexOf is not a function", "TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js:10091:13)
    at next (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:119:54)
    at HTMLDocument.&lt;anonymous&gt; (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:121:9)
    at mightThrow (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js:3557:29)
    at process (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js:3625:12)", undefined
```

Here is the original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609151/load-an-iframe-once-another-iframe-has-finished-loading) and the idea I would like to implement. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to jquery and unable to decipher what the real issue is.

https://jsfiddle.net/1jo83tav/

Comment: *"is not working"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement without any context and debugging details provided

Answer (score 0):

I guess is this problem that `$` is a JQuery variable, add a CDN to your html or something.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`